# What does '@@transducer/step' mean?

Tags: flowtype, ramda.js

The following is from [Ramda's type definitions](https://github.com/flowtype/flow-typed/blob/ef808615f50be517575b4d0be9d64aa7d6fed64b/definitions/npm/ramda_v0.x.x/flow_v0.39.x-/ramda_v0.x.x.js#L3-L7):

```
type Transformer<A,B> = {
  '@@transducer/step': <I,R>(r: A, a: *) => R,
  '@@transducer/init': () => A,
  '@@transducer/result': (result: *) => B
}

declare function into<I,T,A:Array<T>,R>(accum: Transformer<I,R>, xf: (a: A) => R, input: A): R
```

What does `'@@transducer/*'` mean here? I can't find anything about this syntax in the docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually not something specific about flow itself. From Flow's perspective, each of the `'@@transducer/*'` items is just a string literal giving the name of a property in an object.

This Flow declaration says that a `Transformer` is an object with three properties, with those specific strings as their names, and values that are those function types.

It might help to [see an example of a value of that type](https://github.com/ramda/ramda/blob/775ecb2a18416abcbeb831fc1f0de9cebd314ebe/src/internal/_stepCat.js#L9) from the Ramda code. You can see it's just an object with those three keys pointing to specific functions.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer! Has this something to do with fantasy-land spec compliance?

Comment: Not for Fantasy Land. Looks like it's a standard set by transducers-js, a port of Clojure transducers to JS, which created those names: https://github.com/cognitect-labs/transducers-js/blob/6117ae6cb7492916815d078dfa26abc0362f30e1/README.md#transformer-protocol